# MySQL - Left join to subquery very slow

Tags: mysql, left-join

I have been struggling with this problem for a bit. I have a table of entries that need to be audited. I am storing the audit history of the entry in another history. An entry can be audited more than once with different values.

In the end, I need to find the most recent audit status of an entry, along with the original entry details.

Table 1:

`b_response_id | b_response_data | b_response_author | etc.`

The audit history is stored in another table:

`audit_id | b_response_id | audit_status`

I can use this subquery to get the most recent audit status for each entry, and it runs great and fast no problem:

```
SELECT * FROM audit_history b 
INNER JOIN
    (
        SELECT  b_response_id, MAX(audit_id) max_id
        FROM    audit_history
        GROUP BY b_response_id
    ) c ON c.b_response_id=b.b_response_id AND c.max_id=b.audit_id`
```

But when I try to left join this to the original entry table, it is only giving me the entries that have an audit history. I need it to show the entries that have not been audited, as well.

```
SELECT a.*, b.*
FROM entries a
    LEFT JOIN audit_history b
        ON a.b_response_id = b.b_response_id
    INNER JOIN
    (
        SELECT  b_response_id, MAX(audit_id) max_id
        FROM    audit_history
        GROUP BY b_response_id
    ) c ON c.b_response_id=b.b_response_id AND c.max_id=b.audit_id
```

If I change the `INNER JOIN` to `LEFT JOIN` it takes forever. What am I doing wrong?